# Are whistling and clapping haram?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior

I heard that whistling and clapping hands are haram.  I am looking for a clarification and the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Firstly I appreciate your nice question which can be done daily by many people. But in order to achieve better answers, I recommend you to divide it into two separated questions among  Namely 1: Whistling and 2: clapping / Of course as you wish dear good curious mate.

Comment: I have heard that whistling attract shaytan so it is not good to whistle. However I don't think clapping is haram because during salah, if a male need attention for any reason then they should say Subhan Allah. Women on the other hand cannot say Subhan Allah out loud because a woman's voice is part of their awra and if they speak during salah they could distract the males. For this reason it is recommended for a woman to clap if they need attention during salah.

Answer (score 1):

@mate, as I already told you in a comment, replying to both items (whistle and clap) would take a long time and a long answer (s). Anyhow, to help you, I endeavor to answer them in short.

- At the initial stage, about whistle, it looks to be permissible in
  normal forms, and there seems not to be mentioned as an absolute
  haram act. But it can be counted as a haram act if you annoy
  Mu’menin, neighbors and so on. (And although in haram celebration
  such as Raqs(dance) and music …)

---

- In regard to the second part concerning clapping:

  It can be counted as a halal and even haram practice, but it depend
  upon some factors. Thus we can notice it as a halal act unless you
  use it (clapping) in haram ceremonies … or be related to for a
  Mofsedah or sin.

---

For more and extra information by some related traditions (hadith) you can read the following items (which unfortunately solely in Arabic, not English, hopefully it be helpful)

> توزعت النظرة الى الصفير في المصادر الدينية الى اتجاهين؛ يذهب الاول الى
> تقبيح هذا العمل و ذمه و عدم انسجامه مع اخلاقيات الانسان المؤمن، و يذهب
> الآخر الى القول بانه يقع في دائرة المباحات. و سنحاول هنا الاشارة الى
> آية قرآنية و بعض الروايات التي تعرضت لهذا الموضوع.
>
> ---

1. قال تعالى في كتابه الكريم مشيراً الى صلاة المشركين قبل البعثة النبوية الشريفة و كيفية تحركهم العبادي في الكعبة المكرمة: " وَ ما كانَ

> صَلاتُهُمْ عِنْدَ الْبَیتِ إِلاَّ مُكاءً وَ تَصْدِیةً فَذُوقُوا
> الْعَذابَ بِما كُنْتُمْ تَكْفُرُونَ....".[1](https://islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa22755)

---

> 2. ورد في بعض الروايات أن هذه الخصوصية من صفات قوم لوط، و لما كانت صفات هؤلاء القوم ذميمة جداً فمن البديهي ان يكون ادراج تلك الصفة ضمن
>    سائر الصفات إنما يأتي من باب الذم و التقبيح، " نقل أبو الْقَاسم بن
>    قُولَوَیهِ عن الأَصْبَغ قال: سمعتُ علیاً(ع) یقُولُ: سِتَّةٌ مِنْ
>    أَخْلاقِ قوم لوطٍ الجُلَاهِقُ و هو البندُقُ و الخَذْفُ وَ مَضْغُ
>    الْعِلْكِ وَ الصَّفِیرُ وَ إِرْخَاءُ الْإِزَارِ خُیلَاءَ وَ حَلُّ
>    الْأَزْرَارِ".[2](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa22755)

---

> 3. روي عن الامام الصادق (ع) أنه قال في جواب السائل، كيف يعلم قوم لوط أنه قد جاء لوطاً الرجال؟ " قال: كَانَتِ‏ امْرَأَتُهُ‏ تَخْرُجُ‏
>    فَتُصَفِّرُ فَإِذَا سَمِعُوا التَّصْفِیرَ جَاءُوا، فَلِذَلِكَ كُرِهَ
>    التَّصْفِیرُ".[3](https://www.porseshkadeh.com/Question/26544/%C3%98%C2%B9%C3%99%C2%84%C3%98%C2%AA-%C3%9A%C2%A9%C3%98%C2%B1%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%C2%87%C3%98%C2%AA-%C3%98%C2%B3%C3%99%C2%88%C3%98%C2%AA-%C3%98%C2%B2%C3%98%C2%AF%C3%99%C2%86-%C3%9A%C2%A9%C3%99%C2%88%C3%98%C2%AA%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%C2%87-%C3%9A%C2%A9%C3%98%C2%B1%C3%98%C2%AF%C3%99%C2%86-%C3%99%C2%86%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%98%C2%AE%C3%99%C2%86-%C3%98%C2%AF%C3%98%C2%B1-%C3%98%C2%B4%C3%98%C2%A8-%C3%9A%C2%86%C3%9B%C2%8C%C3%98%C2%B3%C3%98%C2%AA)

---

> 4. روي عن النبي الاكرم (ص) مرسلا: "اَنَّهُ قال: اللَّعْبُ بالْكِعَابِ و الصَّفِیرُ بالحمام و أَكلُ الرِّبَا سواءٌ".[4
>
> ---
>
> 5. و لكن ورد في رواية أخرى عن أَحمد بن محمَّدٍ، عن أَحمد بنِ أَبي محمودٍ الخراساني، عن عثمان بن عیسى، قال: رأَیت أَبا الحسنِ الماضي[5]
>    (ع) في حوضٍ من حیاض ما بین مكَّةَ و المدینة علیه إِزارٌ و هو فی الماء
>    فجعل یأخذُ الماء في فِیهِ ثُمَّ یمُجُّهُ و هو یصفِّرُ. فقلْتُ هذَا
>    خیرُ من خلقَ اللَّهُ في زمانه و یفْعَلُ هذا ...».[6]  إلا ان هذه
>    الرواية لا يمكن الاطمئنان اليها لوجود أحمد بن أبي محمود الخراساني الذي
>    لم يترجم له في ما تحت ايدينا من المصادر الرجالية. أضف الى ذلك أن هذا
>    النوع من التصرف و خروج الصوت اثناء مج الماء من الفم لا يصدق عليه
>    الصفير عرفاً. و مع الآخذ بنظر الاعتبار الآية المباركة و الروايات
>    الواردة في هذا المجال يمكن القول: بأن الصفير في حد ذاته يعد من الاعمال
>    غير المحبذة، الا انه يمكن النظر  الى القضية من الزاوية العرفية او
>    المهنة او ما شابه ذلك و كو ن الصفير منطلقاً من أمر عقلائي، كأن يكون
>    وسيلة للتواصل بين العامل و استاذه لعدم وجود وسائل الاتصال اثناء العمل
>    مثلا، فحينئذ لا اشكال في استعمال هذه الوسيلة للتواصل و التفاهم اثناء
>    العمل و في دائرتهم الخاصة، و كذلك الصفير الذي يعتمده الحكام في الرياضة
>    او في الصحارى و الوديان السحيقة التي لا يمكن التواصل فيها من خلال
>    الكلام و الاصوات الطبيعية، و هكذا عمل الرعاة في التعامل مع حيواناتهم و
>    سوقها بالاتجاه المناسب، و الحراس الذين يحذرون السراق و ينبهونهم
>    بوجودهم، و غير ذلك من الحالات التي يقدرها العرف و يتسامح فيها في
>    استعمال الصفير كوسيلة للتخاطب او التنبيه.
>
> ---
>
> [1](https://islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa22755) الانفال، 35. [2](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa22755) الحر العاملي، وسائل الشیعة، ج 5، ص 45، مؤسسه آل
> البیت، قم، الطبعة الاولى، 1409ق. [3](https://www.porseshkadeh.com/Question/26544/%C3%98%C2%B9%C3%99%C2%84%C3%98%C2%AA-%C3%9A%C2%A9%C3%98%C2%B1%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%C2%87%C3%98%C2%AA-%C3%98%C2%B3%C3%99%C2%88%C3%98%C2%AA-%C3%98%C2%B2%C3%98%C2%AF%C3%99%C2%86-%C3%9A%C2%A9%C3%99%C2%88%C3%98%C2%AA%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%C2%87-%C3%9A%C2%A9%C3%98%C2%B1%C3%98%C2%AF%C3%99%C2%86-%C3%99%C2%86%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%98%C2%AE%C3%99%C2%86-%C3%98%C2%AF%C3%98%C2%B1-%C3%98%C2%B4%C3%98%C2%A8-%C3%9A%C2%86%C3%9B%C2%8C%C3%98%C2%B3%C3%98%C2%AA) وسائل الشیعة، ج 11، ص 507. [4]
> النوري، حسين بن محمد تقي، مستدرك الوسائل و مستنبط المسائل، ج 13، ص
> 218، مؤسسة آل البيت عليهم السلام، قم، الطبعة الاولى، 1408ق. [5] يعني
> الامام الكاظم (ع). [6] المجلسي، محمد باقر، بحار الانوار، ج ۷۶، ص ۲۶۵،
> مؤسسة الوفاء، بیروت، 1404ق.

---

**Conclusion:**

It is not counted as a positive practice as what it can be inferred from the traditions (hadiths) and likewise concerning the view of the scholars (Maraja’-al-Taqlid)

---

**References:**

- [islamquest.net (Arabic)](https://islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa22755)   /    [In Farsi (Persian)](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa22755)
- [www.porseshkadeh.com](https://www.porseshkadeh.com/Question/26544/%C3%98%C2%B9%C3%99%C2%84%C3%98%C2%AA-%C3%9A%C2%A9%C3%98%C2%B1%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%C2%87%C3%98%C2%AA-%C3%98%C2%B3%C3%99%C2%88%C3%98%C2%AA-%C3%98%C2%B2%C3%98%C2%AF%C3%99%C2%86-%C3%9A%C2%A9%C3%99%C2%88%C3%98%C2%AA%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%C2%87-%C3%9A%C2%A9%C3%98%C2%B1%C3%98%C2%AF%C3%99%C2%86-%C3%99%C2%86%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%98%C2%AE%C3%99%C2%86-%C3%98%C2%AF%C3%98%C2%B1-%C3%98%C2%B4%C3%98%C2%A8-%C3%9A%C2%86%C3%9B%C2%8C%C3%98%C2%B3%C3%98%C2%AA)

Answer (score 0):

As far as clapping is concerned, there's a difference of opinion. 
Clapping was a way of worshiping God by the pagans. 
So some scholars say that clapping is Haram (forbidden) at any cost, whereas the remaining scholars say that it's not allowed to clap while praying or using it as a way of worship, but otherwise, it's okay. 
You can follow either ruling, the choice is yours.

Hope this helps.